# Custom cell not showing up in tableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, storyboard

I have a custom cell with identifyer 'tweetCell' I have imported this into my tableviewcontroller.h file. I have linked the class to the prototype cell in storyboard. All the UILabels are wired up to the cell but I cannot get the tableview to display the custom cell. It did work? Then overnight stopped?!! I understand that class files need to start with an upper case letter, I have changed this but to no avail. Can anyone spot my error here? Thanks in advance......

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23mysearchhashtag"]];

        NSError* error;

        tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tweetCell";

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *tweetText = [tweet valueForKey:@"text"];

    NSArray *tweetComponents = [tweetText componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; 


    cell.firstDetail.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.secondDetail.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.thirdDetail.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:2];




    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you are using storyboards you should remove the `if (cell == nil) { ... }` part. Tableviews in storyboards automatically create a cell for you, thus the dequeue call will always return a cell. If you have removed that code and you get an exception you will know that your cell identifiers don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write this method `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`? Try like this.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;

    }
```

Comment: not necessary. This is an optional method. And if it does not exist the tableView uses 1 section as default.

Comment: Hi matthias, I've changed the if (cell == nil) { ... } part but it still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: I don't know if it sheds any light on the situation but the line CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; gets the green message "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"